# Why isn't the samba configure script detecting my installed Python modules?

Tags: python, linux, debian

I have used pip to install cryptography and markdown, and they show up when I issue the 'pip list' command. However, while attempting to ./configure samba I receive an error stating that the module could not be found.

The exact error message is 'Unable to find Python module 'cryptography'. Please install the system package: python3-cryptography'.

The same message occurs, but states markdown as well.

I've been trying to follow this [guide](https://www.linuxfromscratch.org/blfs/view/stable-systemd/basicnet/samba.html), but I get hung up at the ./configure line. I installed all of the dependencies, including optional ones. I followed the installation guide, but still cannot get past the check for the cryptography module.

Reasoning for the Samba install is to upgrade to 4.15.5 in order to eliminate the security vulnerability from the current version.

Comment: The easiest thing to do is _read the configure script and see how it's testing_ -- if you know exactly how the test that fails is being run, that provides the information needed to work back and figure out why it fails.

Comment: That said, a few quick questions. Are you using a virtualenv? Does `python` refer to python2 or python3? Does your distro have a `pip3` executable? If so, does `pip3 list` also show the package as installed? Does `python3 -c 'import cryptography'` succeed?

Comment: That said, if you're trying to build samba from upstream source -- _don't_. Patch the Debian package instead of doing a completely unpackaged build. That'll also buy you whatever build-process fixes that Debian package already contains, probably mooting the problem described here.

Comment: (or, y'know, you could use a different package manager's samba; for example, you can install [Nix](https://nixos.org/) on top of Debian, and nixpkgs includes samba 4.5.15 already)

Comment: First off, thank you for the response! I am fairly new to Linux so I appreciate the in-depth answer. `python` refers to python3, distro does have a `pip3` executable and `pip3 list` does show cryptography. However, `python3 -c 'import cryptography'` fails stating `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'cryptography'`

Comment: I'll look into patching the Debian package, seems like that would be much easier!

Comment: What does `declare -p PYTHONPATH` emit? How about `type python3`?

Comment: `declare -p PYTHONPATH` returns `bash: declare: PYTHONPATH: not found` and `type python 3 ` returns `python3 is hashed (/usr/local/bin/python3)`

Comment: Ahh! Did you perhaps install Python from source (the same way you're trying to upgrade samba)? `/usr/local/bin` implies it's one you built yourself instead of one Debian provided.

Comment: ...if samba is trying to use `/usr/bin/python3` instead of `/usr/local/bin/python3`, we may have the cause of the difference in behavior you're seeing.

Comment: Try `/usr/bin/python3 -c 'import cryptography'` -- does that one exit without an error?

Comment: Depends on what's _depending_ on that extra copy, but temporarily -- for the duration of your build process -- you could just modify the PATH to take `/usr/local/bin` out.

Comment: My predecessor is the one who installed python, but it seems like that is the case! Yes, it works.

Comment: Now, in terms of how to never see this class of problem again... if you have the stomach for reading hundreds of pages talking about how almost everyone does software distribution wrong (in ways that lead to the exact kind of problem you're seeing here), Eelco Dolstra's thesis at https://edolstra.github.io/pubs/phd-thesis.pdf describes what the industry is doing wrong and how Nix (the project I previously mentioned) fixes it. :)

Comment: Excellent, I will give that a read! I'll look into using Nix and just upgrading the currently installed version of Samba. Thank you for the help!

Comment: (for a broad definition of "this class of problem" that includes Microsoft's "DLL hell", Gentoo's ABI-incompatible updates, and many other related failures caused by components being swapped out in-place with newer versions that aren't  _really_ compatible with the old ones).